# Middle Selectors Ignored in hxselect

Tags: css, html-xml-utils

I'm attempting to extract some text from a webpage using **hxselect** from **html-xml-utils 7.4**.  According to the man, hxselect will accept a comma delimited list of CSS selectors.  I have three selectors:

```
/usr/local/bin/hxnormalize -x -i 0 -l 5000 https://domain.tld | /usr/local/bin/hxselect -s'\n' 'div#searchfieldouter, div#searchbutton, input.searchfield' > ~/result.html
```

The code performs properly with any one or two of the selectors.  When I use more than two, only the first and last have any effect.  Regardless of the selectors or number of selectors used, the middle ones seem to be ignored.

Is the bug in me or **hxselect**?

Answer (score 0):

Option: hxselect **-c** ....

```sh
hxnormalize -x -i 0 -l 5000 https://domain.tld |
   hxselect -s'\n' -c 'div#searchfieldouter, div#searchbutton, input.searchfield' > ~/result.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a footnote in the book [**Efficient Linux at the command line**](https://efficientlinux.com/), exactly described the same problem what you faced:

> This example uses thress CSS selectors, some old versions of `hxselect` can handle only two. If your version of `hxselect` is afflicted by this shortcoming, download the lastest version from https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils and build it with the command `configure && make`.

So, there's definitely a bug in `hxselect`. The version that used in my environment is 7.7, it has the same problem.
I downloaded the latest version 8.6 and compiled&&installed, it solved the problem.