# Is it possible to define a HTML selector that concatenates multiple selectors and separates them by semicolon?

Tags: html, bash, pup

I'm trying to parse a simple HTML page with [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup).
This is a command-line HTML parser and it accepts general HTML selectors.

I want to select:

```
'div.aclass text{}' #(would be SampleA)
```

and I also want to select:

```
'div.bclass text{}' #(would be SampleB)
```

and I want to concatenate them and insert some custom text to get:

```
SampleA;MYEXTRASTRING;SampleB
```

I want to avoid calling pup more than once as it is slow.

I can select multiple tags:

```
'div.aclass text{}, div.bclass text{}'
```

but this will result:

```
SampleA
SampleB
```

Is there any better choice than pup for this purpose?

(Note: Python is NOT an option as it's very slow for my needs.)

Answer (score 4):

Multiple selectors with pup seem not work, there is an issue here:
https://github.com/ericchiang/pup/issues/59

To achieve your purpose, I would suggest to use **hxselect** command, which can be found inside **HTML-XML-utils**: https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/README

Example:

```
curl -s http://example.com/ | hxselect -c 'body > div:nth-child(1) > h1:nth-child(1)', 'body > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)' -s ';MYEXTRASTRING;' | sed 's/\(.*\);MYEXTRASTRING;/\1/'
```

**curl part:**

curl is used to download html content of http://exmaple.com

**hxselect part:**

hxselect supports multiple CSS selectors. Use **,** to separate these selectors.

-c: print content only, without html tag

-s: separator text after each match. In your case, it's `;MYEXTRASTRING;`

**sed part:**

Because -s separator text will be added for each match, it means it will be added twice. sed is used to remove the last matched separator text.

Comment: Thank you, this would work, however, it  keeps telling me 'Input is not well-formed. (Maybe try normalize?)'. Do  you know any tips to normalize the html before feeding it to hxselect?

Comment: Try `... | hxnormalize -x | hxselect ...`? hxnormalize is another command in HTML-XML-utils, which is used to normalize html

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Works as I wanted originally.

Comment: Sorry, I was faster and did not notice the error msg. hxselect prints: Syntax error at ",". I tried with hxselect -c 'selector1', 'selector2'; hxselect -c 'selector1, selector2', etc.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/html-xml-utils/+bug/1620555 comma seems not working recently

Comment: @Daniel Using "," as separator works well for me. Could you try `curl -s http://example.com/ | hxselect -c 'title,body'`? If not, which hxselect version you have? hxselect -v.

Comment: Running it:
`curl -s http://example.com/ | hxselect -c 'title,body'
Syntax error at ","
(23) Failed writing body`

Version: `hxselect -v
Version: html-xml-utils 7.1`. Which version do you have? I'll try compiling it manually. I just installed this via apt.

Comment: I complied hxselect 7.1. It indeed shows syntax error. Try the latest version 7.7, it works without error.

Comment: It seems (as of version 7.7) that `hxselect` does not really support "multiple" comma-separated selectors, but only two.  When given more than two selectors, it only consider the first and last provided selectors.  Can anyone confirm ?

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou seems so, you're right. It happens to me as well, the middle selectors are ignored...

Comment: @KevinCui [Also confirmed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493639/middle-selectors-ignored-in-hxselect).  I couldn't find a W3C repository to report the bug (apparently [they closed their public Bugzilla last April](https://www.w3.org/2019/01/bugzilla-shutdown.html#migration)).

Comment: The current package (v. 8.0) from https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils no longer has this 2-selector limitation.